# How to override "add to cart" button in wishlist using magento custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, wishlist

How to override template file -

```
vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/column/cart.phtml
```

using custom module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Create `wishlist_index_index.xml` File Under `Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml`

**Add This Code :-**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
         <referenceBlock name="customer.wishlist.item.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName::item/column/cart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

**Create File On `Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/item/column/cart.phtml` And Copy Paste Core cart.phtml file and change as per your requirement.**

---

**If You Used Theme Then Just Copy This File And Put In `Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/column/cart.phtml`**

Comment: Perfect answer!. can you tell me how to do the same for compare template?

Comment: like `Magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/template/product/compare/list.phtml`

Comment: using module or theme?

Comment: using custom module

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your template into your theme directory under `<theme_dir>/<Vendor>_<Module>/view/frontend/templates/item/column/cart.phtml`

Magento will automatically override all template files placed under the same path as in the core modules in your theme's directory.

Comment: I am using module, so is this work?